# Best way to use JSON as a database?

Tags: javascript, json, web-applications

I am creating an offline mobile web app, and am looking at using JSON to replicate some of my database tables and storing that in localStorage. (I am aware of Web SQL Database but it doesn't look particularly future-proof.)

I started with a very basic JSON output from the database, which looks a bit like this:

```
{
  "1": {"id":"1","name":"Hello","alias":"hello","category":"8"},
  "2": {"id":"2","name":"World","alias":"world","category":"3"},
  ...
}
```

However, there is a lot of data in many tables and space could be an issue with the constant repeating of field names. Storing the data like this halves the size:

```
{
  "1": ["1","Hello","hello","8"},
  "2": ["2","World","world","3"},
  ...
}
```

But now I have to reference a piece of data with a numeric index, possibly filling my code with magic numbers. I thought of storing an array like `["id","name"...]` in another variable but the extra lookups seem like they would get messy.

Are there any practical ways to avoid that, but also keeping the Javascript code fairly neat? Any other useful strategies for this kind of development?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

would it be possible to convert it into a format like this:

```
{
   id:{1:1, 2:2, ...},
   name:{1:hello, 2:world},
   alias:{1:hello, 2:world},
   category{1:8,2:3}
}
```

This way, you only store each column once, but you can still easily find things by their id.

Comment: Not a bad idea! I'll try it out and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is not a database.  JSON is a data interchange format.

Comment: In that case, perhaps you could suggest some better alternatives for offline data storage?

Comment: @Alnitak: That is actually the page I was reading before asking this question. It mentioned Web SQL Database (of which the spec is no longer maintained) and IndexedDB (which is not supported by any mobile platform). Which is exactly why I asked the question about using localstorage.

Comment: you didn't mention `localStorage()` in your question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would work across all mobile platforms, but `XML` would be an option.

Comment: Wouldn't XML use *more* storage space, and be harder to parse with Javascript?

Comment: It all depends on the scale of your app, and it depends on your backend.

Comment: In the first tutorial I ever red about jSON, the author called it xml with annorexia. One of the things that save so much space in JSON is that you don't have 2 tags for every element you want to specify. In JSON, the start and end of elements are denoted by curly braces, which makes it shorter. I also find JSON easier to work with than xml, but that's just my humble oppinion.